# Why doesn't Force.com IDE / metadata API download all objects and WF rules?

Tags: metadata-api, force.com-ide

I configured my Force.com project in Eclipse to download ALL standard and custom objects, but it skipped some, e.g. it didn't download CaseTeam, CaseCommnet, EmailMessage, etc. - at first I thought maybe because these are "subobjects" of "Case", but then why did it download "CaseMilestone"?  I don't get it.  Similarly, there's a WF rule on CaseComment, which also didn't get downloaded.

I wanted to be able to download ALL the metadata of an org to check into source control to save the state of the org for rollback purposes - is that not possible?  Do I really need to manually restore some parts of the org that are not downloadable via the metadata API?

Comment: But some of the metadata you specified are not supported (or are not specified) in the Metadata Types documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm). Some objects related to Workflow Rules also are not retrieved by just specifying a WFRule. You have to specify (sometimes) WorkflowFieldUpdates, WorkflowAlert, WorkflowFlowAction (you can check those on the Workflow Metadata page).

Comment: I see the same thing -- I'm going to surmise is that those standard objects are in no way customizable so there is no metadata to manage/deploy